Implementation details of softmax backpropagation in PyTorch
I'm implementing a tiny autograd engine in pure Python with numpy. My code is following the PyTorch API. I'm using gradients calculated by PyTorch's autograd to test my implementation of different operations. I already implemented a handful of operations such as matrix multiplication, addition, etc. However in my implementation of backpropagation for the softmax function I am unable to arrive to the results that PyTorch yields.
I was trying to find the implementation of softmax backprop in Pytorch's codebase and found it for CUDA. I wasn't able to learn the PyTorch way of calculating the softmax derivative from the CUDA implementation though. Also, my code is running on CPU (Apple M1).
In my code, I calculate the Jacobian of the softmax in the standard way:
def get_jacobian(softmax: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    jacobian = []
    for i, sm_i in enumerate(softmax):
        for j, sm_j in enumerate(softmax):
            if i == j:
                jacobian.append(sm_i * (1 - sm_i))
            else:
                jacobian.append(-sm_i * sm_j)
    return np.array(jacobian).reshape(len(softmax), len(softmax))

In the function above, the variable named softmax is a softmax of input arguments.
Then I calculate the gradient of softmax inputs wrt. a scalar value that .backward() was called on (in the testing code below I simply use a .sum function) by the following matrix multiplication:
softmax_grad = parent.grad @ get_jacobian(softmax)
self.grad += softmax_grad

In the code above, parent.grad is a gradient of the previous node in a computational graph. It was computed before as part of backpropagation. In the testing code below, parent.grad will be the gradient of a sum operation (valued [1., 1.]). self.grad is where I'd like to store the gradient computed for the softmax.
Now, in my testing code:
import torch
import numpy as np
import numpy.testing as npt

def test_softmax():
    assert_softmax_gradients(np.array([2, 4]))

def assert_softmax_gradients(data: np.ndarray):
    # GIVEN
    my_tensor = Tensor(data)
    torch_tensor = torch.Tensor(data)
    torch_tensor.requires_grad = True
    
    # WHEN
    my_tensor.softmax().sum().backward()
    torch.sum(torch.softmax(torch_tensor, dim=0)).backward()

    # THEN
    npt.assert_allclose(my_tensor.grad, torch_tensor.grad.numpy())

The error I'm getting in tests is:

E           Mismatched elements: 2 / 2 (100%)
E           Max absolute difference: 5.24995939e-08
E           Max relative difference: 1.
E            x: array([1.387779e-17, 1.249001e-16])
E            y: array([7.105047e-09, 5.249959e-08], dtype=float32)

with x being my gradient and y being PyTorch's gradient.
I know that numerical stability might be the biggest issue here but I was able to get really similar results with other operations that I implemented (e.g. for matrix multiplication my results are within 1e-06 from the PyTorch results.
I also generated a computational graph for the above operation using graphviz, which I include below:

I would like to learn why I'm not getting the similar results as PyTorch's softmax and what I can do to fix this.
